# Global solution of $y'=y^4-x^8$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered a problem while working on a mathematical analysis exercise. The problem is as follows: we need to determine the initial value condition $y(x_0)=y_0$ for the ordinary differential equation (ODE) $y'=y^4-x^8$ in order to find a global solution, i.e., a solution defined for all $x$ in the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone provide me with assistance?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3):

This ODE doesn't appear to have a closed-form general solution: neither Maple nor Wolfram Alpha find one. But it looks like the solution for $y(0) = 0$ (which is an odd function) is defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$.  In fact, it seems to be $-x^2 + 1/(2 x^5) + O(1/x^{12})$ as $x \to +\infty$ and $x^2 + 1/(2 x^5) + O(1/x^{12})$ as $x \to -\infty$.